# Is there better solution than forceUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Data ( fragment ) keep by my component state looks like that:

```
[
    {
        batchId: 1234,
        ...
        jobRowData: [
            {
                assignmentId: 12345,
                isSelected: false,
                ...
            },
            {
                assignmentId: 12346,
                isSelected: false,
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        batchId: 1235,
        ...
        jobRowData: [
            {
                assignmentId: 12347,
                isSelected: false,
                ...
            },
            {
                assignmentId: 12348,
                isSelected: false,
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to change isSelected and I do it using below method:

```
handleIsSelectedChangedJob(selectedIdsData){
    let jobRowData = this.state.batchRowData.find((x) => {return x.batchId === selectedIdsData.batchId}).jobRowData
    let jobRowItemData = jobRowData.find((x) => {return x.assignmentId === selectedIdsData.assignmentId})
    jobRowItemData.isSelected = !jobRowItemData.isSelected // do the update
    // this.setState({batchRowData: [...this.state.batchRowData]}) // this also works instead of this.forceUpdate()
    this.forceUpdate() // how to refresh view according to update 2 lines above ?
}
```

where argument selectedIdsData could looks like that:

```
{assignmentId: 12346, batchId: 1234}
```

My question is: is there another way of refreshing view than doing this.forceUpdate()? Commented line above it also do the job, but it operates on whole state object instead on one changed property.

Comment: setState is the recommended way to handle such updates and not forceUpdate, even though it operates on the entire object since during render, react will intelligently render the differences

Comment: You should always use `setState` where you can, forceUpdate is really not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely! You should never modify the state directly (by reference) and that's exactly what is happening inside of `handleIsSelectedChangedJob`. You have to create a new state and call `setState`:

```js
handleIsSelectedChangedJob({assignmentId, batchId}) {
  const dataIndex = this.state.batchRowData.findIndex(x => x.batchId === batchId);
  const data = this.state.batchRowData[dataIndex];
  const itemIndex = data.jobRowData.findIndex(x => x.assignmentId === assignmentId);
  const item = data.jobRowData[itemIndex];

  const newItem = {...item, isSelected: !item.isSelected};
  const newData = {
    ...data,
    jobRowData: [].concat(
      data.jobRowData.slice(0, itemIndex),
      newItem,
      data.jobRowData.slice(1 + itemIndex)
    )
  };

  this.setState({
    batchRowData: [].concat(
      batchRowData.slice(0, dataIndex),
      newData,
      batchRowData.slice(1 + dataIndex)
    )
  });
}
```

As you can see, it's far more code, but now it's not mutating the state, only copying as much as needed. Of course, there's plenty of libraries to do it. It's still not perfect, as it's not good to read `this.state` and then call `this.setState` - using `this.state(state => diff)` would be safer:

```js
handleIsSelectedChangedJob({assignmentId, batchId}) {
  this.setState(state => {
    const dataIndex = state.batchRowData.findIndex(x => x.batchId === batchId);
    const data = state.batchRowData[dataIndex];

    // Same as above...

    return {
      batchRowData: [].concat(
        batchRowData.slice(0, dataIndex),
        newData,
        batchRowData.slice(1 + dataIndex)
      )
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: It won't work, as `itemIndex` and `dataIndex` are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This should let you do what you desire:

```
handleIsSelectedChangedJob(selectedIdsData){
    const _batchRowData = ...this.state.batchRowData;
    const batchIndex = _batchRowData.findIndex((x) => x.batchId === selectedIdsData.batchId);
    const jobIndex = batchIndex < 0 ? -1 : _batchRowData[batchIndex].jobRowData.findIndex((x) => x.assignmentId === selectedIdsData.assignmentId);

    if (batchIndex < 0 || jobIndex <  0) {
        return;
    }

    _batchRowData[batchIndex].jobRowData[jobIndex].isSelected = !batchRowData[batchIndex].jobRowData[jobIndex].isSelected;

    this.setState({ batchRowData: [..._batchRowData] });
}
```